# $A\subset M$ is sequentially compact if and only if every infinite subset of A has an accumulation point in $A$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Claim**

$A\subset M$ is sequentially compact if and only if every infinite subset of A has an accumulation point in $A$

**Proof**

Since $A$ is sequentially compact, every sequence in A has a sub-sequence that converges to a point in $A$.  Thus, if there's a infinite subset of A, we can also guarantee that this subset also has an accumulation point in $A$.

Conversely, if every infinite subset of A has an accumulation point in A,(...)

How could I prove the converse case? I only know the infinite cases. but need to generalize it to the level of every sequence.

Comment: Consider any sequence, it is an infinite set, so it has an accumulation point, which is created by a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Any sequence in $A$ with a finite number of points must have a convergent subsequence.  Any sequence with an infinite number *is* an infinite subset of $A$...

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $A$. Now you have two cases. Either the set $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is finite or infinite. If it is finite then there must be a member $a$ of the sequence that occurs infinitely many times; so take that subsequence of which the limit is $a$.

Next suppose the above set is infinite. Then it has an accumulation point, say $x$, in itself by supposition. Hence $(a_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $x$.